# Which eclipse galileo version is supported by jdk 1.7.0_71

Tags: java, eclipse, galileo

i have downloaded and installed jdk 1.7.0_71 on my windows 7 home basic 64 bit lenovo laptop.
Now i need to download IDE.
I was recommended to install eclipse Galileo( as i will be using the same in future) IDE for Java EE Developers but i cant find 64 bit version on eclipse website.
Only 32 bit windows version is available.
Will the 32 bit version works for 64 bit and will it be compatible the jdk i have installed?

Comment: Probably none. Galileo is really old.

Comment: The JDK and Eclipse must both be 32 bit or both 64 bit. Just to repeat Galileo is very old.

Answer (score 0):

JDK and Eclipse are both different they are not dependent on each other, but if your system is 64bit then use JDK and eclipse 64 bit. you can [download eclipse](https://eclipse.org/downloads/) from here you can go for eclipse **Luna** it is latest release.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 64 bit version because 64 bit Windows was not very popular at the time Galileo was released. You need 32 bit JDK to use 32 bit Eclipse. It should work on 64 bit Windows though. Are you sure you are supposed to use 6 years old Eclipse?